# what is the best way to increment?

Tags: netlogo

Netlogo is sadly missing a c-style ++. What work arounds do you use?

```
Let x x+1
```

Is fine but when it becomes

```
Set Goat-drinking-holes Goats-drinking-holes + 1
```

I long for C operators like +=, -= %= etc.

What solutions have you come up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, `set Goat-drinking-holes Goats-drinking-holes + 1` is the only way to do it. However, there is a better way to do things for many of the common use cases of incrementing. For instance, iterating through a list can be done with [`foreach`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach) and [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map). If you specify what you're trying to accomplish with incrementing, people may be able to help you find something more concise and expressive.

Edit in response to comment:

For sake of completeness, you can do something like this if you *really* want, but I don't recommend it. The requirement of explicit `set`s in NetLogo is intentional. NetLogo (as well as other Logos) draws much inspiration from Lisp and other functional languages. Anyway, here it goes:

```
to increment [ var-name ]
  run (word "set " var-name " " var-name " " + 1")
end
```

You then use it like so: `increment "Goat-drinking-holes"`. This creates the string `"set Goat-drinking-holes Goat-drinking-holes + 1"` and then runs it like code. Pretty ugly in my opinion, and it will be slow if used in tight loops. Note that this won't work on local variables as they won't be in scope for `increment`. I would really recommend avoiding this if you can.

If you find yourself needing to increment or use other, similar destructive operators a lot, there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do. I know there are many individuals on SO that would be happy to help. NetLogo has a lot of stuff that C-family languages do not (besides the whole ABM stuff of course) that experienced programmers often don't even know to look for. There is a reason that NetLogo lacks those operators.

Comment: Don't know netlogo; but is it not possible to make a function that calls the same `set`?  Like an `increment` (or `incr` if brevity is pursued)?  I searched on passing parameters by reference and found something about [changing variables by passing a variable name to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265782/how-to-change-agents-variable-by-passing-variable-name-and-value-to-a-function)

Comment: @Bryan Head thank you put my longing to rest. Netlogo is the best. Don't forget REPEAT.